# If I have 640 input filters in a web page, what is the max number of combination of filters I can have?

Tags: math

If I have 640 input filters in a web page, what is the max number of combination of filters I can have?

I have a system I need to scrape for work. With 640 input fields revealing different result. How many possible reports can I get from 640 input fields.

Answer (score 2):

If they are binary, 2^640 (193 digits). Otherwise, somewhere between bazillions and infinity.

The number of combinations is not the same as the number of reports, though. Some combinations could yield the same results.